# Accessing shell executables from php in apache server

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell

The server box which I have handles 100k concurrent requests currently, I am in need to use php command `exec($cmd)` or `shell_exec($cmd)` and execute a shell file (a file with extension somefile.sh) and perform some file moving and executing files.

How does the apache server handle this operation will it crash my server based on concurrent connections ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are none. All these things are handled by the os.

Comment: yes, my question: is the apache server handling access of same unix shell executable repeatedly accessed by several 1000's of requests.

Comment: That was not you question! But no, it does not. Every request creates a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) if you're looking how to exec programs from shell using PHP.